# java ee spring error

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am facing a problem, It doesn't redirect to a jsp(HTTP 404) from the controller although I entered correctly a valid `url` address that can be treated by the controller. Here is my `web.xml`, the controller and what the debugger shows me.

I entered http://localhost:8080/AccessControl/produits.aspx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>ApplicationAccessControl</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.aspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>default.aspx</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**AgentAdministrativeController.java in the controller package**

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import dao.AgentAdministrative;
import services.AgentAdministrativeMetier;
import services.SessionBean;

public class AgentAdministrativeController {

    @Autowired
    AgentAdministrativeMetier services;

    @Autowired
    private SessionBean sessionBean;

    @RequestMapping(value={"/connnexiontrait","/default"})
    public String verifier(Model model,@RequestParam String username,@RequestParam String motdepasse,@RequestParam int labo){
        Long t;
        String arg1;

        t=services.verifaccess(username, motdepasse, labo);

        if (t.intValue()==0)
        {
            arg1="Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe ou numero de laboratoire sont incorrectes ,veuillez les ressaisir " ;
            model.addAttribute("erreurs", arg1);
            System.out.println("succes");
            return "connexion";
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("succes");
            return "produits";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/produits"})
    public String verifie(Model model)
    {   
        return "produits";
    }
}
```

**This is what Debugger shows me.**

```
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AccessControl' did not find a matching property.
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server built:          Feb 15 2015 18:10:42 UTC
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server number:         8.0.20.0
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Name:               Linux
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Version:            3.16.0-23-generic
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Architecture:          i386
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Version:           1.7.0_75-b13
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/sami/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/sami/Téléchargements/apache-tomcat-8.0.20
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/sami/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/sami/Téléchargements/apache-tomcat-8.0.20
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/sami/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/sami/Téléchargements/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/endorsed
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFOS: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFOS: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 885 ms
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Démarrage du service Catalina
mars 29, 2015 8:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
mars 29, 2015 8:32:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
hibernate framework !! 
mars 29, 2015 8:32:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
mars 29, 2015 8:32:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
mars 29, 2015 8:32:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 2937 ms
mars 29, 2015 8:32:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'action'
```

This is `application-servlet-config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/Pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the request mapping be just ´/´? AFAIR it looks for a path with this name in your case. Can give it a try tomorrow morning.

Comment: Can you post `application-servlet-config.xml`. I think there is something missing in there?

Comment: @Ria yes I've placed this jsp in webcontent folder ,not  in web-inf .Yes , But in what time?

Comment: @minion <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/Pages/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>     I have produits.jsp placed in /web-inf/Pages

Comment: Can you post the whole xml? How are you scanning your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your controller.

1. Your controller is missing `@Controller` annotation.
2. Your application-servlet-config.xml does not have spring mvc elements, hence your controller is not even being picked up when server starts. You can controller mapping in your logs, if its picked up.

So try using the below application-servlet-config.xml instead and see. I would also suggest seeing a spring mvc tutorial, if this does not resolve it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
  <context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="your.controller.package" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/Pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>     
</beans>
```